# Rx .Net trigger an action based on objects datetime property (ie date passes from future to past)

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm fairly new to the reactive world so please forgive my ignorance.

I have an Observable stream of objects (coming from a [DynamicData](https://github.com/reactiveui/DynamicData) cache if that has any bearing) and I want to be able to trigger an action to update this object when a DateTime on this object elapses.

So for an example object:

```
    class TestObject
    {
        public DateTime TriggerDate { get; set; }

        public void SomeUpdate(string avalue) => Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss} {avalue}");
    }
```

The best I can come up with is this and I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it, it feels a bit messy?

```
        var testobjects = new List<TestObject>
        {
            new TestObject{ TriggerDate = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(4) },
            new TestObject{ TriggerDate = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(8) },
            new TestObject{ TriggerDate = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(12) },
            new TestObject{ TriggerDate = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(16) },
            new TestObject{ TriggerDate = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(20) },
            new TestObject{ TriggerDate = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(24) },
            new TestObject{ TriggerDate = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(28) },
        }.ToObservable();

        testobjects
            .Select(x =>
            {

                // return an observable (with the one item) that I can delay and subscribe on
                var updateStatus = Observable.Return(x)
                    .Delay(x.TriggerDate - DateTime.Now) // delay until the time passes
                    .Select(test =>
                    {
                        test.SomeUpdate("hi");

                        return test;
                    })
                    .Do(
                        _ => Debug.WriteLine("onNext"),
                        ex => Debug.WriteLine($"onException {ex.Message}"),
                        () => Debug.WriteLine("onComplete"))
                    .Subscribe();

                // needed ?
                //_cleanup.Add(updateStatus);

                return x;
            })
            .Subscribe();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to do with that `.Do` section?

This code is nearly equivalent, with improved subscription handling, to what you have. The one difference is the 'onNext' message happens before the 'Hi':

```
testobjects
    .SelectMany(t => Observable.Return(t)
        .Delay(t.TriggerDate)
        .Do(
            _ => Debug.WriteLine("onNext"),
            ex => Debug.WriteLine($"onException {ex.Message}"),
            () => Debug.WriteLine("onComplete")
        )
    )
    .Subscribe(t => t.SomeUpdate("Hi"));
```

---

**Edit**:

`SelectMany` flattens whereas `Select` doesn't. In this case, if you were to use `Select`, your type going into the `Subscribe` would be `IObservable<IObservable<TestObject>>`: For each original `TestObject` in the observable, we create an observable that has a single `TestObject`. `SelectMany` flattens that into `IObservable<TestObject>`. You could accomplish the same effect with `Merge`. `Select(f).Merge()` is roughly equal to `SelectMany(f)`.

Regarding Subscribe actions: I'm guessing you mis-read something; I would recommend the opposite. Observables should have pure-functional code; subscriptions are the best place for side-effects.

Comment: The Do was just internal debugging really.  Can I ask why the SelectMany over the Select?
Also, I've read in places that using Subscribe to perform an action wouldn't be best practice?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I think you might be right that I've misread - lots of info to take in - might have confused it with the advice regarding not using async in Subscribe.